# How to upload Multiple images with multiple string Parameters in single request

Tags: android, upload

I want to upload multiple files with single request in android.

```
// for pick files

getImages(){
 Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Pictures"), 
                REQUEST_DOCUMENT_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        haveIMAGES = false;
        if(data!=null){
            if(data.getClipData()!=null){
                List<Uri> docURI = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                    Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    docURI.add(imageUri);
                }
                haveIMAGES = files.size() > 0;
                if(haveIMAGES){
                   uploadFiles(docURI);
                 }

            }
        }

    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

// for upload files

```
uploadFiles(List<Uri> docURI){
 // params need to send with file
  Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("pid", "random id");
    params.put("uid", "random id");
    params.put("rating", "any number");
    params.put("description", "any string");
```

// files parameter name = imageFiles
}

How can i upload files using imageFiles as key with other parameters

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a third-party library like [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). The request to the server should be `multipart`.

Comment: I know about retrofit, I tried but i am unable to do it, It would be very helpful if you provide me some example about multipart using single key images

Comment: Here you can find an example of Retrofit multipart request sending file: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap